# Difference between What's your another tip for that? and What's another tip for that?

Tags: grammar

I want to see the difference between

> What's your another tip for that?
>
> What's another tip for that?

Do they both seem grammatically correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**What's your another tip for that?** is not grammatically correct, and it's not clear what it means.  *Tip* is a countable noun, so it needs no more than one determiner, but both *your* and *another* are determiners.

Comment: @busi You could say *What's another tip* ***of yours*** *for that?*